# How to check all the checkboxes in rows using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to AngularJs. I have the code below where I have a table and rendering the content of the table using Angularjs. I have a selectAll checkbox on the header on checking of which I need all the checkboxes in the table to get selected. Since I can sort, filter the content, I am not understanding how to select all the checkboxes of the table. Can you please let me know how to get this implementation.

Also added a plunker for this code

[Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/EcdrWNEuTw6hMvVirLnE?p=preview)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
      <div class="ibox-title">
        <h5>Hosts {{ currentPage }}</h5>
         <!--<button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning pad-btn" type="submit" ng-click="reset()" style="float:right;">Refresh<i class="fa fa-history"></i></button>-->
      </div>
      <div class="ibox-content">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-4 m-b-xs">
                  <div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group">
                      <label class="btn btn-sm btn-white"> <input type="radio" id="option1" name="options" ng-model="pageSize" value="10">10</label>
                      <label class="btn btn-sm btn-white"> <input type="radio" id="option2" name="options" ng-model="pageSize" value="25">25</label>
                      <label class="btn btn-sm btn-white"> <input type="radio" id="option3" name="options" ng-model="pageSize" value="50">50</label>
                      <label class="btn btn-sm btn-white"> <input type="radio" id="option4" name="options" ng-model="pageSize" value="100">100</label>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-4 m-b-xs">
                  <div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group">
                      <label class="btn btn-md btn-primary"> <input type="radio" id="refresh" name="options" ng-model="action" value="refresh" ng-change="handleRefresh()">Refresh</label>
                      <label class="btn btn-md btn-info"> <input type="radio" id="reset" name="options" ng-model="action" value="reset" ng-change="handleRefresh()">Reset</label>
                      <label class="btn btn-md btn-warning"> <input type="radio" id="export" name="options" ng-model="action" value="export" ng-change="handleRefresh()">Export</label>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 pull-right">
                  <div class="input-group">
                      <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Host" ng-model="name">
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" ng-change="updateHosts()" ng-model="all_hosts"/></td>
                  <td>
                  <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'name'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                      Hostname
                      <span ng-show="sortType == 'name' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                      <span ng-show="sortType == 'name' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                  </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'application'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                          Application
                          <span ng-show="sortType == 'application' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                          <span ng-show="sortType == 'application' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                      </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'environment'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                          Environment
                          <span ng-show="sortType == 'environment' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                          <span ng-show="sortType == 'environment' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                      </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'tier'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                          Tier
                          <span ng-show="sortType == 'tier' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                          <span ng-show="sortType == 'tier' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                      </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'changes_summary'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                          Changes
                          <span ng-show="sortType == 'changes_summary' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                          <span ng-show="sortType == 'changes_summary' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                      </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'change_last_checked'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                          Last Updated
                          <span ng-show="sortType == 'change_last_checked' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                          <span ng-show="sortType == 'change_last_checked' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                      </a>
                  </td>

              </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr dir-paginate="host in newHosts | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:name | itemsPerPage:pageSize
        " pagination-id="host" current-page="currentPage">
                  <td><input type="checkbox" ng-change="update(host.id)" ng-model="host_id"/></td>
                  <td>{{host.name}}</td>
                  <td>{{host.application}}</td>
                  <td>{{host.environment}}</td>
                  <td>{{host.tier}}</td>
                  <td><span class="label-danger"><a class="linkref" href="/details/{{host.id}}">{{host.changes_summary}}</a></span></td>
                  <td>{{host.changes_last_checked | date:"MM/dd/yyyy"}}</td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
              <div class="range-label">Displaying</div>
              <dir-pagination-controls pagination-id="host" on-page-change="pageChangeHandler(newPageNumber)"></dir-pagination-controls>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: loop through your data and set property that each checkbox is bound to by `ng-model`

Comment: But the date might be filtered or sorted. can u please give an example? I am not quite getting it.

Comment: bind `ng-model` for individual checkboxes to a property of each host object and update that property when you `check all`. Create a demo in plunker that we can work with

Comment: Added the plunker Url. I am able to handle the click events of the individual checkboxes but not select all checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

On **thead** change your checkbox line for this:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-change="updateHosts()" ng-model="allHosts"/></td>
```

On **tbody** change your checkbox line for this:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="host.checked"/></td>
```

Change your `$scope.newHosts` for this:

```
$scope.newHosts=[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Pradeep",
      "application": "Angularjs",
      "checked": false
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Praveen",
      "application": "NodeJs",
      "checked": false
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Raj",
      "application": "Java",
      "checked": false
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Ram",
      "application": "Dontnet",
      "checked": false
    }
  ];
```

Finally, add this method:

```
 $scope.updateHosts = function (){
  $scope.newHosts.forEach(function(host){
    host.checked = $scope.allHosts;
  });
};
```

Aditional: Get rid of your update method.

Now, when you click on each checkbox, the variable `checked` will change inside `$scope.newHosts`.

### Edit

If you just want to check the filtered ones, try this:

```
    <tr dir-paginate="host in filteredHosts = ( newHosts | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:name | itemsPerPage:pageSize)" 
        pagination-id="host" current-page="currentPage">
```

Comment: But in that case, all the hosts will be checked inside the updateHosts funtion when I apply the filter. But when i remove the filter also all the hosts will be checked.

Comment: When you check the **head** checkbox all your body checkbox will be checked, and when you uncheck the **head** checkbox all will be unchecked. Isn't it what you required?

Comment: I have say 100 records. I apply the filter and only 10 records gets displayed with the filter records. When I check the select all checkbox, only 7 checkboxes rows should be checked  and when I uncheck only 7 should be unchecked. By your logic, I guess all the 100 records will be checked and unchecked?

Comment: Also, if I remove the update function and rely on the `$scope.newHosts` to get the objects with `checked`as true, do you mean, filtering all the records say 100 to see how many of them are checked? please let me know. I am seeing this as a good design.

Comment: I don't know how your paginate framework works, but changing the repeat like **edit** you can have just the filtered ones in a variable. With this you can have `filteredHosts.length`. It's better if you use an array for the filtered ones separate of your newHosts.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a module called `md-data-table`. Take a look at [demo](https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table#demo).